# Inspect creation of PATH in osx to find broken path in PATH

Tags: osx, path

Is there any tool or command that can show you your PATH, and for each element in it, what file injected it into the path?

There is an invalid path in my PATH that is causing fish shell to complain:

```
set: Warning: path component /usr/bin/local may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
~ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin/local /Users/tcarpent/Development/erl_libs/rebar3 /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/sbin /opt/X11/bin
```

The problem is, I don't know where this entry is coming from. It is *not* in /etc/paths, or in my fish config, or in .bash_profile, .profile, or .bash_rc. So, I'm at a loss.

EDIT: more info. `/Users/tcarpent/Development/erl_libs/rebar3` is set by my fish shell. `/usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/sbin /opt/X11/bin` is set by `/etc/paths`. So it is something that comes "after" my fish conf.

Edit2: when I delete my whole fish configuration, I get `/usr/local/bin /usr/bin/local /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/sbin /opt/X11/bin`

Edit3: I did a grep in all of `/etc` and this string is nowhere to be found.

Comment: No. If you run `env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin fish -l -c 'echo $PATH'`, is the directory listed? If it is the problem is in your fish configuration, otherwise it's in the OSX configuration.

Comment: @Gilles that line blows up: `~ env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin fish -l -c 'echo $PATH'
env: fish: No such file or directory`

Comment: @giles I triedd commenting out my whole fish configuration and i still have the problem. However, `/Users/tcarpent/Development/erl_libs/rebar3` is set by my fish configuration, and all the ones after are set by my /etc/paths, so I thought the culprit was "after" my fish conf.

Comment: If `fish` isn't in `/usr/bin`, you'd need to use the full path to `fish`, or add it to the `PATH` setting on that line. But removing your fish configuration shows the same thing: it's coming from what OSX sets up, not from your fish configuration.

Comment: @Gilles that does show the string: ```~ env PATH=/usr/local/bin fish -l -c 'echo $PATH'
set: Warning: path component /usr/bin/local may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin/local /Users/tcarpent/Development/erl_libs/rebar3 /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/sbin /opt/X11/bin```. Essentially this shows the samw as what I print.